# Getting rid of welcome message in Spyder Python IDE (Anaconda)

Tags: ipython, anaconda

I am on Windows 7 64bit.

Is there a way to customize the welcome message in the Spyder IDE IPython console? (I am using the Anaconda distribution.) Preferably, starting with a plain: `In [1]:`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to change the command line that launches the console. I'm not sure what Sypder uses. Looks like Ipython in the screenshot. 
For ipython qtconsole:

```
ipython qtconsole --no-banner
```

For jupyter qtconsole:

```
jupyter qtconsole --no-banner
```

For a plain cmd console:

```
ipython console
```

or

```
ipython --no-banner
```